# Fake truffle oil

Tags: oil, truffles

I've been told that most white truffle oil is fake.

Is this true? How do you determine whether it is fake? All of the white truffle oil I've bought has a sliver of truffle floating around in the bottle... surely that is enough proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true, most truffle oil is not flavored with truffle, it is rather flavored with dithiapentane(an odorant).  You should be able to tell by the label if it is in fact flavored by the actual truffle or dithiapentane.  Not sure I would say that a sliver of truffle in the bottle would be enough to know for sure.

On a side not I recently had the opportunity of meeting chef Sergi Arola of La Broche, who While he was shaving some fresh truffle said that truffle oil was one of the worst ingredients that he has seen chefs use, and that people need to just stay away from it.

I have to admit the real truffle shavings were amazing,  but not all of us can afford them.

Comment: Truffle and truffle oil are vastly different, but "one of the worst ingredients" is definitely laying it on a little thick.  The oil is so potent that it's very easy to go overboard and wreck the balance of the dish (truffled mash potatoes being one of the worst offenders I've had).  Used as a subtle accent though, it can be quite excellent.

Comment: I agree. I use the oil, it's all I can really afford. If I had the option though I would probably grab the real truffle every time.